# Ionic 3 app - finding the source of error

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I have an Ionic (latest version) app with Ionic Pro error monitoring running on it. In the last days, I got a lot of errors like these:

```
Uncaught (in promise): 0 -  {"totalSize":0,"position":0,"total":0,"loaded":0,"lengthComputable":false,"cancelBubble":false,"returnValue":true,"srcElement":{"statusText":"","status":0,"response":"","responseType":"","responseXML":null,"responseText":"","upload":{"onprogress":null,"onloadstart":null,"onloadend":null,"onload":null,"onerror":null,"onabort":null},"withCredentials":false,"readyState":4,"timeout":0,"onreadystatechange":null,"ontimeout":null,"onprogress":null,"onloadstart":null,"onloadend":null,"onload":null,"onerror":null,"onabort":null,"__zone_symbol__loadfalse":[{"type":"eventTask","state":"scheduled","source":"XMLHttpRequest.addEventListener:load","zone":"angular","runCount":0}],"__zone_symbol__errorfalse":[{"type":"eventTask","state":"running","source":"XMLHttpRequest.addEventListener:error","zone":"angular","runCount":2}]},"defaultPrevented":false,"timeStamp":1524546205615,"cancelable":true,"bubbles":false,"eventPhase":2,"currentTarget":{"statusText":"","status":0,"response":"","responseType":"","responseXML":null,"responseText":"","upload":{"onprogress":null,"onloadstart":null,"onloadend":null,"onload":null,"onerror":null,"onabort":null},"withCredentials":false,"readyState":4,"timeout":0,"onreadystatechange":null,"ontimeout":null,"onprogress":null,"onloadstart":null,"onloadend":null,"onload":null,"onerror":null,"onabort":null,"__zone_symbol__loadfalse":[{"type":"eventTask","state":"scheduled","source":"XMLHttpRequest.addEventListener:load","zone":"angular","runCount":0}],"__zone_symbol__errorfalse":[{"type":"eventTask","state":"running","source":"XMLHttpRequest.addEventListener:error","zone":"angular","runCount":2}]},"target":{"statusText":"","status":0,"response":"","responseType":"","responseXML":null,"responseText":"","upload":{"onprogress":null,"onloadstart":null,"onloadend":null,"onload":null,"onerror":null,"onabort":null},"withCredentials":false,"readyState":4,"timeout":0,"onreadystatechange":null,"ontimeout":null,"onprogress":null,"onloadstart":null,"onloadend":null,"onload":null,"onerror":null,"onabort":null,"__zone_symbol__loadfalse":[{"type":"eventTask","state":"scheduled","source":"XMLHttpRequest.addEventListener:load","zone":"angular","runCount":0}],"__zone_symbol__errorfalse":[{"type":"eventTask","state":"running","source":"XMLHttpRequest.addEventListener:error","zone":"angular","runCount":2}]},"type":"error"}
at c (polyfills.js:3:19752)
at ? (polyfills.js:3:19174)
at ? (polyfills.js:3:21242)
at t.invoke (polyfills.js:3:14976)
at Object.zone._inner.zone._inner.fork.onInvoke (vendor.js:4982:33)
at t.invoke (polyfills.js:3:14916)
at r.run (polyfills.js:3:10143)
at ? (polyfills.js:3:20242)
at t.invokeTask (polyfills.js:3:15660)
at Object.zone._inner.zone._inner.fork.onInvokeTask (vendor.js:4973:33)
```

Is there any way to find the source of this errors? Is the problem in my code or is it just an Ionic/Angular bug?

Comment: So you need to use "source maps" to capture errors in your typescript code. The error is most likely "yours" but to trace it back you need to do sync maps. See this: https://ionicframework.com/docs/pro/monitoring/#source-maps

Comment: I've uploaded the source maps to Ionic Pro, but I only get the error from my question, no other useful details

Comment: do you use firebase or something else similar/particular? this sounds like an error with xhr